# Increase the time hints (yellow pop ups) show up in the website

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, popup

Could someone increase the time that hints are displayed?

Every time I up-voted an answer I was getting a small pop-up message:

> You have not voted questions in a while. Consider up-voting this question.

The message shows up as soon as clicked (which is good) and goes away without confirmation (which is good), but it is gone too fast (feels like less than a second, which is bad). Because I keep forgetting to watch for it, It took me some up-votes on different answers to be able to fully read the message.

I bet some people would simply cast another vote on a random answer to see the message again, undermining the voting system.

Comment: *It took me some up-votes on different answers* I may hope those answers were up-vote worthy ....

Comment: They actually were. And this was part of the problem. I would keep telling myself: "Next time, I will pay more attention to the message". But I would go back to my tasks and I would forget I had to watch it. But as you highlighted, some people may just up-vote to see the message again, thus I think it is a valid fix/feature.

Comment: FWIW, if I'm reading [the code](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js) correctly, the actual time the message is shown for should be either 2.5 seconds or 40 milliseconds per character, whichever is greater. For this particular message, that should work out to approximately 3 seconds.

Comment: Also, I think you should be able to un-upvote and re-upvote the same answer to get the message to show up again. (I'll try to test this the next time I see it; unfortunately, it seems the message has worked a bit too well on me, so I rarely see it nowadays.)

Comment: "I bet some people would simply cast another vote on a random answer to see the message again, undermining the voting system." Actually this entire feature is a clever plot to increase reputation randomly.

Comment: Ohhhhh so *that* is what it said.... Only saw the yellow like popup once, but I only got a glance of it before I carried on coding, not giving me enough time to read it in full.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, if this is the case, I am about to say that fade-in and fade-out are included on these 3 seconds. Maybe it would be good to add another 2 seconds to it. The message does not display again if the same answer is un-upvoted and re-upvoted . I tried. I bet you can upvote un-upbvote another answer, this may bring the message again. I have not tried it though.

Comment: @nico: I just managed to test this, and you *can* get the message again by un-upvoting and re-upvoting the same answer multiple times. However, apparently the message itself doesn't appear all the time, but only randomly (apparently about half the time), presumably to make it seem less repetitive. Also, while testing this, I learned that if you upvote and un-upvote the same answer too many times (I think the limit is about 25-30 times or so) your vote gets locked in(!).

Comment: Also, 3 seconds seems pretty close to what I'm seeing. Looking at the code, the nominal display time should include the 0.4 sec fade-in but not the 0.4 sec fade-out, so it should more or less balance out. Still, adding an extra second or two probably wouldn't hurt, and could make the message easier to read even for people who read more slowly.